# Check if value in column in Database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have code to insert element into a Database:

```
def NewElement(new_user,new_pass):
        querycurs.execute('''INSERT into Database (user,passw) values (?,?)''',(new_user,new_pass))
```

I want to execute the given statement only when the given value os new_user is not already present in the user column in the table. How can i do so?

Comment: Sounds like you need a database level constraint on the `user` column.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `user` column, either with a table constraint, with a unique index, or with a primary key.

Then replace INSERT with [INSERT OR IGNORE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).